# Are there any tools for discovering tandem repeats around a variant in a VCF file?

Tags: vcf, repeat-elements

I know for example `PolyX` from Pierre's [`Jvarkit`](http://lindenb.github.io/jvarkit/) to find the number of repeated REF bases (homopolymers) around a position in a VCF file as described [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/140069/) exists.

I would like to know however if there tools that describes tandem repeats around a reported variant (TR) up to 6 repeated bases. I can imagine 3 different scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

```
chrK    posY    C     G

TR of (ATC)
____________v
ATCATCATCATCGATGATAC
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
chrK    posY    A     T

             TR of (AACT)
            v____________
CAGTCGATTGGATAACTAACTAACT
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
chrK    posY    C     A

TR of (AG)    TR of (AG)
____________v__________
AGAGAGAGAGAGCAGAGAGAGAG
```

If you know any tools in mind that can be used for VCFs, I'd really appreciate citing them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a bit, I found a couple of tools that take as input BAM files. I did not test them yet:

- [GangSTR](https://github.com/gymreklab/GangSTR)
- [lobSTR](https://github.com/mgymrek/lobstr-code)
- [hipSTR](https://github.com/tfwillems/HipSTR)
- [Tandem Repeat Finder](https://tandem.bu.edu/trf/trf.html) (thanks to Michael G.'s answer)

If I find more tools, I will update this post. After testing them, I will come back to share my feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The old program for doing this last updated in 2016 is Tandem Repeat Finder (TRF) [here](https://tandem.bu.edu/trf/trf.html). This will not find a microsatellite sequence at a given variant, but instead find all tandem repeats in the genome and their position. It has been around for a long time.

You would then simply screen this output against the position of your variant. TRF may have been modified however to perform a search within given nucleotide boundaries.

Comment: Yes I also saw that software but I didn't give it a proper test. thanks for your Answer !